# Rest API Limits Except For Paging

Tags: rest

I have a REST service that I would like to limit the usage of clients.  The API is as follows.

```
/api/accounts/search/{page}/{page_size}
```

Since the record can return a large recordset, I use paging as described in the sample above using {page} and {page_size}

I'm going to use a table to track a user's session that will contain the following columns.

```
* Client IP
* Date Created
* Any Other Table To Use If Required
```

The rule I want to use is to prevent too many requests from the same IP as follows:

```
1. New Search Request 1 per minute
2. Except if from part of a paging result set from the result.  Ex page 2, 3, 4, etc. I don't want the rule for #1 to exist here.
4. Disallow making a new request while they are pulling data down from #2  ( I want to avoid someone from scraping the information).
```

Steps #2 and #3 is were I'm not sure how to logically do or information to track to accomplish this.   Due to the server limitations, I'm trying to avoid my server's resources from being exhausted by someone scraping our data continuously.

I'm looking for tips or ideas on how best to accomplish this and would appreciate some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of page numbers, you might consider a `next` link. This is a common pattern, and used by many different APIs. You can embed it in your JSON responses, the `Link` HTTP header or adopt a standard hypermedia JSON format such as HAL, Siren or others.

For a user to find the next page, all they have to do is grab that url and do the next fetch. Now you're no longer stuck on page numbers, you can embed any data you want in that next page, including some hard to guess string that can act as a one-time token for the next page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Looking into right now and seems like this will work for me